# Strange Connection Problem

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I recently bought a Mac Book Pro (M1, 2020) and am running Mac OS Monterey (12.1).

Ever since I bought the computer, I am having a strange problem with my home WLAN internet connection. While the connection speed seems fine when measured for example with https://www.speedtest.net/ and surfing the web works, the computer seems to have difficulty *establishing* connections in other applications, such as SSH connections to servers, MS Office products (Outlook, MS Teams, OneNote, ...) and also other programs such as ZOOM. Additionally, the connection to the Appple App Store does not work at all and OS Updates only work sporadically (most often they terminate with a connection error).

Interestingly, **all** these problems magically disappear, if I switch to a tethered connection from my mobile phone and my WLAN connection works just fine with other operating systems (Windows, Android). Hence, it seems to be the combination of my WLAN with the MAC OS, which is causing the problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the problem occur wherever you place the laptop within your home, or only in specific places?

Comment: The problem occurs everywhere, i.e., its not a problem with the WiFi reception (also I get good speeds for common speed tests in the browser).